# ggplot2: geom_ribbon with alpha dependent on data density along y-axis for each x

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, alpha

Is there a way in ggplot2 to produce a geom_ribbon (or other area based geom) with a varying alpha based on the density of points?

The following code produces 50 noisy sine waves, with random x-values for each sample. I don't want to draw every single point as I might want a thousand or more resamples, so I'd like to summarise all these points.

A simple method would be to draw a geom_ribbon covering 95% quantiles. However, firstly this isn't that easy to calculate given the x-values aren't the same for each resample; normally you'd calculate the pointwise quantiles at each of the 100 x points.

Instead I'd like to have ribbon covering the entire area where samples are located, with a continuous alpha gradient, i.e. the ribbon would be darkest in the middle near the actual line and very light at the outlier points. Is this possible in ggplot2?

```
library(ggplot2)

num_points = 100
num_samples = 50

x = seq(0, 4*pi, length.out=num_points)

sim <- lapply(1:num_samples, function(f) {
    x = runif(num_points, 0, 4*pi)
    y = sin(x) + rnorm(num_points, 0, 0.4)
    data.frame(x=x, y=y)
})

sim.df <- do.call(rbind, sim)
actual = data.frame(x=x, y=sin(x))

ggplot(sim.df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
    geom_line(data=actual, colour='blue', size=1.5)
```

[image: Plot of noisy sinewaves]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option is to use quantile regression to get the y-values for each quantile at each x-value and then plot those using `geom_ribbon`.

```
library(splines)
library(quantreg)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
```

1. Set quantiles for density ribbons:

   ```
   nq = 50 # Numbre of quantiles
   qq = seq(0,1, length.out=nq)
   ```
2. Run the quantile regression for each quantile. I've used a flexible spline function to get a good fit to the sine function:

   ```
   m1 = rq(y ~ ns(x,10), data=sim.df, tau=qq)
   ```
3. Create data frame for use by geom_ribbon to plot density quantiles.

   Create a data frame of regression quantile predictions using `predict`:

   ```
   xvals = seq(min(sim.df$x), max(sim.df$x), length.out=100)
   rqs = data.frame(x=xvals, predict(m1, newdata=data.frame(x=xvals)))
   names(rqs) = c("x", paste0("p",100*qq))
   ```

   Reshape the data so that the predictions for each quantile serve as the `ymax` for one quantile and the `ymin` for the next quantile in succession (with the exception that the first quantile serves only once as the first `ymin` and the last quantile serves only once as the last `ymax`). Put the data in long format so that we can group by quantile in ggplot:

   ```
   dat1 = rqs[, -length(rqs)]
   names(dat1)[-1] = paste0(names(dat1)[-1])
   dat2 = rqs[, -2]
   names(dat2)[-1] = paste0(names(dat1)[-1])

   dat1 = melt(dat1, id.var="x")
   names(dat1) = c("x","group","min")
   dat2 = melt(dat2, id.var="x")
   names(dat2) = c("x","group1","max")

   dat = bind_cols(dat1, dat2)
   ```
4. Now create the plot. We map the quantiles to the `alpha` aesthetic, and then use `scale_alpha_manual` to set the alpha values to be higher for quantiles closer to 0.5 and lower for quantiles closer to 0 and 1:

   ```
   ggplot() +
     geom_point(data=sim.df, aes(x,y), alpha=0.1, size=0.5, colour="red") +
     geom_ribbon(data=dat, aes(x=x, ymin=min, ymax=max, group=group, alpha=group), 
             fill="blue", lwd=0, show.legend=FALSE) +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_alpha_manual(values=c(seq(0.05,0.9,length.out=floor(0.5*length(qq))),
                                 seq(0.9,0.05,length.out=floor(0.5*length(qq)))))
   ```

[image]

Here's another example, but with data that has a varying standard deviation:

```
sim <- lapply(1:num_samples, function(f) {
  x = runif(num_points, 0, 4*pi)
  y = sin(x) + rnorm(num_points, 0, abs(0.7*cos(x))+0.1)
  data.frame(x=x, y=y)
})

sim.df <- do.call(rbind, sim)
```

Now just run all of the code we created earlier to get this plot:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just a note for those using larger datasets, you'll need to set alpha=sort(group) in the geom_ribbon call, as otherwise it thinks group 59 is next quantile from 591.