# Fuzzy Line (Region) in R

Tags: r, line, gradient, fuzzy

I want to draw a fuzzy line instead of a simple line like the image below:

[image]

I **don't** want fill in area between 2 lines with a color like that polygon function do:

[image]

I want to draw a line or a region that covers all of the point in the dataset like a **gradient shaded** that is light at both ends of the lines and is dense in the middle of the line (Almost like the picture that is located below)

[image]

How can i do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37329255/496488) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You can also look  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714492/legend-with-geom-line-and-geom-ribbon)

Comment: @eipi10, see picture updated please. Can i came to this conclusion with the way you said? Also It was somewhat complicated.